# How to check when user visited(been active) the site last time

Tags: php, wordpress

Been looking for a solution for hours and didn't found one 
I've tried to use the following code

```
function user_last_login( $user_login, $user ){
update_user_meta( $user->ID, '_last_login', time() );
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'user_last_login', 10, 2 );
```

but I figured out that wp_login action hook only triggered when user logs in manually (writing the username and the password and clicking log in) and it's not triggered if he's logged in automaticly ...

Another thing I've tried was this code

```
add_action('init', 'wpse_session_start', 1);
function wpse_session_start() {
   if(!session_id()) {
      update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_last_login', time() );
      session_start();
    }
}
```

but this one don't do the work too...
Would be very greatfull somebody can offer a way to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

```
function user_last_login( $user_login, $user ){
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, '_last_login', time() );
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'user_last_login', 10, 2 );
```

For the above function you tried, you have to use following line where you need the last login values.

```
get_user_meta( $user->ID, '_last_login', true );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need the time stamp to update **every time** the user visits a page (not just when they log in), the `wp_login` hook will obviously not work. Instead, you can hook into [`init`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init), which runs on every page load:

```
// Update time stamp
function set_user_last_active() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_last_login', time() );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'set_user_last_active' );
```

You can then get the time stamp using:

```
get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_last_login', true );
```